# How can I return specific columns of a row only when another cell in that row contains a specific character like a space? Excel formula route

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a tab of financial information with many columns; in the next tab I'm interested in only seeing 4 of these columns, only for the rows where a specific cell in that row contains a space inside it.

[image: Starting point]

is what the raw data looks like.

[image: Goal output]

is what the new tab should ideally look like.

I was thinking of using the subgroup cell as the "identifier" cell where something looks inside it to check if there's a space, and if there is, 4 specific columns get listed next to it.

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using either of the following formulas, assuming no Excel Constraints :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A11</kbd>

```
=CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(B1:F1,FILTER(B2:F4,ISTEXT(TEXTAFTER(B2:B4," ")))),1,2,3,5)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A8</kbd>

```
=CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(B1:F1,FILTER(B2:F4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",B2:B4)))),1,2,3,5)
```

---

For older versions, you may try:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$F$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$4)-ROW($B$2)+1)/
(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",$B$2:$B$4))),ROW(ZZ1)),{2,3,4,6}),"")
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow I'm so jealous some ppl just know* how to combine functions to simply work. Both formula sets worked, and I ended up implementing the A8 cell simply because I understand more how IsNumber & Search work together hahah

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with:

[image]

Formula in `B6`:

```
=FILTER(HSTACK(B1:D4,F1:F4),(ROW(B1:B4)=1)+COUNTIFS(B1:B4,B1:B4,B1:B4,"* *"))
```

Comment: Thanks JvdV! Not going to lie but I spent a good amount of time trying to follow the logic flow through the formulas but just couldn't make it click for me in my head. (When I edited it to fit my cells, it did give me the solution I wanted though!) As long as it works though